# I'm using ng-bootstrap modal component,and it does not show

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

When I try to show it, it gives the folowing error :

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): 0
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:712) [angular]
    at NgbModalRef._reject (zone.js:638) [angular]
    at NgbModalRef.dismiss (modal-ref.js:54) [angular]
    at :4200/vendor.bundle.js:45949:82 [angular]
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.es5.js:3647) [angular]
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:239) [angular]
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:186) [angular]
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:126) [angular]
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:90) [angular]
    at EventEmitter.Subject.next (Subject.js:55) [angular]
    at EventEmitter.emit (core.es5.js:3621) [angular]
    at NgbModalWindow.dismiss (modal-window.js:21) [angular]
    at NgbModalWindow.backdropClick (modal-window.js:13) [angular]
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (NgbModalWindow_Host.html:1)
```

It was working, and it suddenly stoped working !
here is its official doc https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal

Comment: what specific versions of angular and bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Show us your markup and your code.

Comment: use `.catch()` with `.then()`, it will fix it